# Angular: Observable model property does not exist

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular

After upgrading from Angular 2 to Angular 4 I get these errors when trying to compile using AOT:

```
Property 'total' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
```

This is how I have used observables until now...

First I have assigned a variable like this:

```
public myData: Observable<any>;
```

Then I have a call to my service which I subscribe to like this:

```
this.mySubscription = this.apiService.get('URL-HERE')
                        .subscribe(
                            response => this.myData = response,
                            error => this.feedbackService.displayError(<any>error),
                            () => this.feedbackService.stopLoading()
                        );
```

This works in development mode (ng serve), and I can use stuff like `*ngFor` to iterate over the results.

After getting these errors I tried to add a model class like this:

```
export class MyData {
    total: number;
    count: number;
    data: Array<any> = [];
}
... rest of component here
```

And then use it with my observable like this:

```
public myData: Observable<MyData>;
```

But I still get errors when trying to compile:

```
Property 'total' does not exist on type 'Observable<MyData>'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

This is what the service method looka like:

```
return this.http
        .get(apiUrl + apiPath, {headers: headersWithToken})
        .timeoutWith(appSettings.maxTimeHttpCalls, Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw(this.feedbackService.timeout())))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch((err: Response) => {
            return err.json();
        });
```

All values (including `total`) exists on the returned JSON and I can use it in my HTML without a problem.

Comment: try this `public myData: MyData;`

Comment: Why is `this.myData = response` if it's an observable? response is a stream of something?

Comment: What line is the error refering to?

Comment: Updated with example from my service call. I get hundred of these errors when compiling since I have used this setup on all my API calls throughout the app.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out AOT doesn't like elvis operators in Angular 4.

I kept `Observable<any>` on all components and wrapped all entries containing stuff like `{{myData?.total}}` inside an `*ngIf` check (and removed ?) and the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just add a bit more context here, I think your error is actually happening in the `component.html` file right?

So basically, you have something like this:

`my-component.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    data$: Observable< MyType >;

    construct(private myService: MyService) {
        this.data$ = myService.getStuff();
    }
}
```

And let's assume your service, `my-service.service.ts` looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    getStuff(): Observable< MyType > {
        this.http.get('www.example.com/data').map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Finally, you have your `my-component.component.html` and **currently** it looks like this:

```
<div class="my-data">
    {{data$?.global?.statistics | async}}
</div>
```

When compiling this you would get the error

`Property 'global' does not exist on type 'Observable<MyType>'.`

And there's a very good reason for this. We need to remember that we're using objects that could **hold** observables but may not be observables themselves. What the HTML file above is saying is that `data$` and `global` are a part of the object and `statistics` is the `Observable`. So the structure would look like this:

```
data$: {
    global: {
        statistics: Observable< MyType >;
    }
}
```

But actually what you want is:

```
data$: Observable< MyType >;
```

So to fix this, you need to go into your HTML and tell it that `data$` is the `Observable` and not the objects within it:

```
<div class="my-data">
    {{(data$ | async)?.global?.statistics}}
</div>
```

Now it knows that the `data$` object is the `Observable` and the things after it are a part of the returned object and not the `Observable` class.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing in terms of changed compiler behaviour, might have less to do with aot and much more with updated typescript (if you were on anything earlier than I think angular 2.4.9, you had to have used typescript 2.0 or lower, and angular 4 requires 2.1 or higher).

Given the upgrade to typescript, you may need to also revisit your tsconfig settings and make sure they are still doing what you want.